# Updating MS Access table with a specific value based on another table

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to update a yes/no column in a table based on a lack of matches from a second table as follows:

```
UPDATE Table1 
INNER JOIN Table2 
ON (Table1.Date_last_action = Table2.MaxOfDate_last_action) 
AND (Table1.Office = Table2.Office) 
AND (Table1.Response_ID = Table2.Response_ID) 
SET Table1.IsDeprectated = 1
WHERE (([Table2].[MaxOfDate_last_action] Is Null));
```

OR

```
UPDATE Table1 
INNER JOIN Table2 
ON (Table1.Date_last_action <> Table2.MaxOfDate_last_action) 
AND (Table1.Office = Table2.Office) 
AND (Table1.Response_ID = Table2.Response_ID) 
SET Table1.IsDeprectated = 1;
```

Neither of which is working.

What I'm aiming for is that when the update query is executed that the IsDeprecated column is set to True for all rows in Table1 that DO NOT have a matching row in Table2

Is this possible?

[Edit following Tim's comment]

[image: Data Sample]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use exists logic along with a subquery:

```
UPDATE Table1 t1
SET t1.IsDeprectated = 1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table2 t2
                  WHERE t1.Date_last_action <> t2.MaxOfDate_last_action AND
                        t1.Office = t2.Office AND
                        t1.Response_ID = t2.Response_ID);
```

Comment: Alas just returns a list of rows on the IsDeprecated column

Comment: @Seamus Please try using `NOT EXISTS` instead then.  This seems to agree with the logic you want in your updated question.

Comment: I get the correct number of rows returned but it's not automatically updating the IsDeprecated column to True (1)